# CSS styling and structuring content in a card with vertical and horizontal separators

Tags: css

I am looking to structure the statistics data with vertical and horizontal separators as shown in the image below. I have the outer shadowed card ready inside which I need to have this statistical data formatted for display. Any guidance is most appreciated in advance, bit of a novice here. ([sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgEjF.png))

```css
.divSquareStats{

text-align:center;   width:94vw;  height: 28vh;    overflow: hidden;margin-left: 12px;margin-top: 15px;
transition: border-radius 0.15s ease;
border-radius: 30px;
font-family: Nonito;
font-weight: bolder !important;
font-size: 13px;
cursor: pointer;   border:5px solid white; float: left;   }
 
.z-depth-3 {

box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);   }
```

```html
<div tappable col-12 text-center class="divSquareStats z-depth-3">   
 <span style="margin-top:10px; font-family:Roboto; float: left" class="user-name">
 Statistics goes here
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be achieved with tables.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please add a relevant code snippet of what you have so we have something to help you with

Comment: please, for the love of Buddha, do not use tables for layout, as @MuhammadUmerHassan suggested. Bad, bad practice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think this should point you in the right direct. Let me know if you need more help.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row separators">
        <div class="column one-third"></div>
        <div class="column one-third"></div>
        <div class="column one-third"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-separators">
        <div class="column one-half"></div>
        <div class="column one-half"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.separators .column:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```